# Array not updated when changes occur Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

There is an `Observable` that sends an array of offers to my component.
But when the list is changes (one is deleted) it does not change the list that I get in the component.

I've tried it with `ngOnChanges` to subscribe to the list again and update the list in my component, but it doesn't detect any changes on the list.

When I use `ngDoCheck` it worked, but I want a little less drastic solution for this..

**offer.service.ts**:

```typescript
    // observable of offers list
      public getAll(): Observable<Offer[]> {
        return of(this.offers);
      }
```

**component.ts:**

```typescript
    offers: Offer[] = [];
      selectedOfferId = -1;
    
      constructor(private offerService: OfferService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.offerService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
          this.offers = data;
        });
      }
    
      ngOnChanges(): void {
        this.offerService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
          this.offers = data;
        });
      }
```

Comment: You need to create a subject and subscribe to it, https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/subject

Comment: @lissettdm thanks, but I don't understand where to use is. Do I need to implement it in my service of the ts of my component?

Comment: do you add or remove items outside the component?

Comment: I remove them in another compnent wich shows the "offer" wich calls a method from the service

Comment: So the list is changes in the service but the component still shows the "old" list because it doesn't refresh

Comment: I think you should create the subject in OfferService class, when you apply changes to the list, at that moment you should notify the changes to all subscribers, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can communicate between components using an Observable and a Subject (which is a type of observable), I won't go too much into the details, you can fin more info [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/subject), there are two methods: Observable.subscribe() and Subject.next().

**Observable.subscribe()**

The observable subscribe method is used by angular components to subscribe to messages that are sent to an observable.

**Subject.next()**

The subject next method is used to send messages to an observable which are then sent to all angular components that are subscribers of that observable.

**A workaround solution:**

offer.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class OfferService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();
    
    //...

    getOffers(message: string) {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }

    removeOffers() {
      //...remove logic
      this.subject.next({this.offers})
    }

}
```

component.ts:

```
 subscription: Subscription;

 ngOnInit(): void {
       this.subscription =  this.offerService.getOffers().subscribe(offers => {
          //...
       })
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now!

Comment: happy to help ;)