# How can i listen to changes in my observable through my whole app

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am new to rxjs and angular world. This is how i take data in reactive way with async in my app.

**user service**

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
users$ = this.http.get<any[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
```

**APP COMPONENT HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="users$ | async as users">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let user of users">{{ user.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**APP COMPONENT TS FILE**

```
constructor(private userService: UserService) { };
users$: Observable<any[]> = this.userService.users$;
```

the data is fetched and is showed in the HTML. But what if i have child component in my app component
where i want to show also the fetched data. Also i need when there are changes in my app component, so when new data is arraived in my observable users$, that to be reflected though all app including my child component. I know that i can use Input() decorator so send the data to the child,but i need something like shared service. Also Input() will work just for child components, i need changes to be reflected on whole app.

So when i have for example button in my app component that needs to fetch new data from the server

```
<button (click)="getOtherData()">Get other data</button>
```

```
getOtherData() {
}
```

then i make new api call to fetch the new data and to make that changes through whole app

Comment: This will help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64728809/array-not-updated-when-changes-occur-angular-10/64729917#64729917

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with **BehaviorSubject** ,that you can subscribe to messages like any other observable .Below is the code snippet and [sample stackblitz of the usage of behaviour subject](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-behaviorsubject-example?file=src/app/two/two.component.ts)

```
 export class sharedService{
   constructor(){}
   private user = new BehaviorSubject<string>('abc');
   castUser = this.user.asObservable();
   
   editUser(newUser){
     this.user.next(newUser); 
      }
   }
```

In component

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.sharedService.castUser.subscribe(user => this.user = user);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create BehaviourSubject and use it in multiple components. Handle Null checks if your components and html pages

user service:

```
public users$ = new BehaviourSubject<any[]>(null);
fetchUsers() {
    this.http.get<any[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .pipe(take(1)).subscribe((users) => {
       this.users$.next(users)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To share the same data within your app you should create a service which is provided in root. In this service you will expose an observable with your data.

Pseudocode:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class DataService {

public data$: Observable<TYPE> = this.getData().pipe(
 shareReplay(1) // to NOT execute an additional HTTP-call per subscriber
)

constructur(private http: HttpClient) {}

private getData(): Observable<TYPE> {
  return this.http.get(...)
}
}
```

And then you can have several components/services listening to this by

```
Component1 {
data$: Observable
constructor(dataService: DataService){}
 ngOnInit() {
 // get reference. Now you can do whatever you like with this data
  this.data$ = this.dataService.data$ 
}
}
```

And you can do this everywhere and all consumers will share the same data.